# To implement SSL on JMX

Tags: ssl, jmx

I am new to jmx and ssl. Now I am trying to implement jmx with ssl.

I have created keystore and truststore as specified in the link http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=953.

And implemented a simple java application in eclipse as in  https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/jmx_connecting_through_firewalls_using. I configured kestore and truststore files like this,

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Certificates\\keystore.jks");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
```

Now I have to run the application with jboss. So I edited properties - services.xml. set the same properties with  tag like this,

```
<attribute name="Properties">
         javax.net.ssl.trustStore = C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\certificates\\truststore.jks 
     </attribute>
```

It is working now. My doubt is is this the correct way of implementing jmx and SSL with jboss? or do I have any other way to implement it? please tell me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

its a right way, you can [check this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wxsinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.extremescale.admin.doc/cxsjmxsec.html) link for more details, if you need to run your application in jboss you can specify the properties in wrapper conf